# What is the dual space of the Banach space of sections for a Riemann manifold

Tags: geometry, functional-analysis

Let $(M,g)$ be a compact, closed Riemannian manifold. The space of continuous sections of the tangent bundle becomes Banach with with

$|\gamma|:= sup_{x\in M}|\gamma(x)|$

Is it possible to idenitify the dual space?

Comment: Radon measures with values in 1-forms would be the name I'd use.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks for the response. Could you elaborate a little more? Where does the radon measure part come in? And these are probably just continuous forms, right?

Comment: The dual space of the space of continuous functions has a concrete interpretation as the space of Radon measures. Your situation is just the manifold version of that.

Comment: And no, there are non-continuous forms there. For example: fix a point p and a 1-form on p. The map which sends a vector field X to the evaluation of that 1-form at X(p) is not a continuous 1-form. It is sort of a Dirac measure.